# PostgreSQL 1 to n relationship, query rows where n is an exact match from input

Tags: postgresql, relational-division

Let's say I have two tables, orders and order_details. Order details contains the products ordered in an order. For clarity, there is an example below:

Orders:

```
+----------+
| order_id |
+----------+
|        1 |
|        2 |
|        3 |
|        4 |
|        5 |
+----------+
```

Orders_details:

```
+----------+-------------+
| order_id |  product_id |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 |           1 |
|        1 |           4 |
|        2 |           3 |
|        2 |           4 |
|        3 |           3 |
|        3 |           4 |
|        3 |           5 |
|        4 |           4 |
|        4 |           3 |
+----------+-------------+
```

How would I find orders that exactly match a list of products?
With the above data, given the list of products [3, 4], the query should return two orders, #2 and #4. The order #3 does not match because the product #5 was also ordered.

I can do it that way, but it feels like I'm missing something:

```
select order_id
from orders_details
group by order_id
having array_agg(product_id) @> array[3, 4] and array_agg(product_id) <@ array[3, 4]
```

Comment: Additionnal question: Does this specific problem have a name?

Comment: Yes it has a name - and even a tag. I think the array solution is probably the most efficient one in Postgres. Alternatively you could use `having array_agg(product_id order by product_id) = array[3, 4]`

Answer (score 1):

I am not too familiar with Postgres' array syntax, but you may handle this problem via an aggregation with two assertions:

```
SELECT o.order_id
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Orders_details od
    ON o.order_id = od.order_id
GROUP BY
    o.order_id
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN od.product_id NOT IN (3, 4) THEN 1 END) = 0 AND
    COUNT(DISTINCT od.product_id) = 2;
```

### Demo

The first count in the `HAVING` clause asserts that no `product_id` other than 3 and 4 occur.  But this would still leave behind orders have only one `product_id`.  The second count in the `HAVING` clause asserts that there were in fact two `product_id` present, which would implied to be 3 and 4.